# Angular 12 Getting Id of Selected Product

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I want to get the id value of the selected product in my Angular 12 project, I used NgModule for this, but unfortunately it does not work. What is the reason for this?

Note: It happens when I use it in a different component, but not here

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Aracın Markası</label>
            <select
              [(ngModel)]="brandId"
              (click)="getModels(brandId)"
              class="form-select"
              aria-label="Model"
              formControlName="brandId"
            >
              <option  *ngFor="let brand of brandList"
               [ngValue]="brand.id">
               {{ brand.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: You already have selected value in brandId

Comment: I want to give this selected value as a parameter to the get Models function, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: you can "split" [(ngModel)] : `<select [ngModel]="brandId" (ngModelChange)="brandId=$event;getModels($event)"/>` but think if is neccessary your function. if only is change the value of the variable is innecessary. you has a two-way binding